# Compare todays date to a stored date in a SqfLite database

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

I want to compare todays date with a stored date in a SqfLite database and do something if the date matches.

My table:

```
Vara.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    this.id = json[DatabaseCreator.id]; // int primary key
    this.varuNamn = json[DatabaseCreator.varuNamn]; //text
    this.utgangsDatum = json[DatabaseCreator.utgangsDatum]; //text
  }
```

My code so far:

```
Future getVaraDate() async {
    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
    var date = now.toString().substring(0,10);
    final sql = '''Select * from ${DatabaseCreator.varuTable} where ${DatabaseCreator.utgangsDatum} == "$date" ''';
    List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery(sql);
    // What to do here?

}
```

output:

```
I/flutter ( 8118): [{id: 36000291452, varuNamn: hej, utgangsDatum: 2019-05-19, isDeleted: 0}]
```

I'm stuck, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't see what your problem is. `result` now contains a `List` of `Map` objects (only one object based on the output). Just access the date, use `DateTime` to parse it and compare the two...

Comment: @Herohtar I've tried for example: var list = result.first.
But that gives me:  I/flutter ( 2406): {id: 36000291452, varuNamn: hej, utgangsDatum: 2019-05-20, isDeleted: 0}

Comment: `result.first` gives you the first `Map` in the `List`. Next you need to access the date value. (Hint: `list['utgangsDatum']`)

Comment: @Herohtar Thank you for your help. I've figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

So what solved it was the following:

```
    Future getVaraByDate() async {
        DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
        var date = now.toString().substring(0,10);

        final sql = '''Select * from ${DatabaseCreator.varuTable} where ${DatabaseCreator.utgangsDatum} == "$date" ''';
        List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery(sql);
        if(result.isNotEmpty){
          var firstResult = result[0];
          var dateResult = firstResult.values.elementAt(2);
          return dateResult;
          print(dateResult);  
        } else {
          print("No matches");
        }
      }
```